# How to delete an array of pointers

Tags: c++, memory

I've been brushing up on my C++ as of late, and I have a quick question regarding the deletion of new'd memory. As you can see below i have a simple class that holds a list of FileData *. I created an array to hold the FileData objects to be pushed into the list. When ReportData is destructed I loop through the list and delete each element. My question is, how can i delete the array when I'm done using reportData, so that I do not have any memory leaks?

### Report.h

```
class REPORTAPI ReportData {
public:

        ReportData()
        {
        }

        virtual ~ReportData()
        {
                printf("Starting ReportData Delete\n");
                for (list<FileData*>::iterator i = ReportFileData.begin(), e = ReportFileData.end(); i != e; )
                {
                    list<FileData*>::iterator tmp(i++);
                    delete *tmp;
                    ReportFileData.erase(tmp);
                }

                for (list<SupressionData*>::iterator i = ReportSupressionData.begin(), e = ReportSupressionData.end(); i != e; )
                {
                    list<SupressionData*>::iterator tmp(i++);
                    delete *tmp;
                    ReportSupressionData.erase(tmp);
                }

                ReportFileData.clear();
                ReportSupressionData.clear();

                printf("Finished ReportData Delete\n");
        }

        list<FileData *> ReportFileData;
        list<SupressionData *> ReportSupressionData;
}


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) FileData* __stdcall createFileData(string fileName, long recordCount, long addPageCount)
{
        return new FileData(fileName, recordCount, addPageCount);
}
```

### Main.cpp

```
        ReportData *reportData = createrd();

        if (reportData != NULL)
        {
                CreateFileDataFunc createfd (reinterpret_cast<CreateFileDataFunc>(GetProcAddress (dll, "createFileData")));

                const int num_files = 5;
                FileData *fileData[num_files];

                char buff[256] = {'\0'};
                for (int i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
                {
                        sprintf(buff, "test: %d", i);
                        fileData[i] = createfd(buff, 1, 1);
                        reportData->ReportFileData.push_back(fileData[i]);
                }

                delete reportData;
                reportData = NULL;

                delete [] fileData; // this is throwing an access violation error:
                                    //EAccessViolation: 'Access violation at address 326025AF. Write of address 00000008'.


        }
```

--- I removed the delete oprations from the ReportData dtor
and I'm now looping and deleting:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
            {
                delete fileData[i];
            }
```

This is easier to understand then having to rely on a separate object's dtor to clean up memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. fileData is an automatic (stack) variable. You didn't allocate it with new, so you don't delete it.

[Edit: also I'm not sure, but I think you could face problems deleting those FileData objects from main.cpp, considering that they were allocated in some dll. Does the dll provide a deleter function?]

Comment: createfd is a function pointer that returns a new instance of FileData though.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on how createfd allocated its return value?  If createfd returns a pointer that it new'ed, then someone still has to delete it.

Comment: Always try to match your new and delete. Are you doing a new of FileData?

Comment: The fds themselves are deleted in ~ReportData (assuming they're still on the list, which they are if this is all the code). At least, if push_back succeeds then they are. If that throws then a FileData object is leaked.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not dynamically allocated, so you don't need to delete it.  Each element, however, is pointing to a dynamically allocated object (from your comment):

> createfd is a function pointer that returns a new instance of FileData though

What you need to do is loop over the elements of the array, and free each of them.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
{
    delete fileData[i];
}
```

Comment: He already deletes each pointer on the list, in the destructor of ReportData. So if he also deleted each pointer in the array, he'd be doing it twice.

Comment: if one of those destructors throws you will have a memory leak, try to use smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
// allocate on the stack, no manual delete required
FileData *fileData[num_files];

// allocate on the heap, must delete after usage
FileData *fileData = new FileData[num_files];
// ..
delete [] fileData;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete or clear either of the two lists - this will be done for you by the default destructor. Assuming that the pointers the lists contain (to "arrays"? I'm not clear) have been dynamically allocated, you need to delete them. However, you can (and should) avoid having to do this explicitly by making the lists contain std::vectors or suitable smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

*"My question is, how can i delete the array when I'm done using reportData, so that I do not have any memory leaks?"*

That's the wrong question. The right question is "who should delete these FileData objects?", and the answer is "whoever constructs them, ideally, in this cae Main.cpp". Farming out the job to reportData is awkward and precarious; doing the job *twice* (once in the ReportData destructor and again in Main.cpp) violates memory.

If you *must* destroy the objects in ~ReportData(), just don't do anything about them in Main.cpp. Then your code will be correct. Horrible, but correct.

Comment: With an array of pointers, delete[] will delete the array but not what the pointers point to.  Either use smart pointers or individually delete all pointers - provided, of course, that you should delete them in the first place.

Comment: David Thornley, yes, I completely missed that error on first readin, I have just eaten a few of my words. Michael G, I would probably do as Jimmy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about wrapping FileData* with a smart pointer?

The problem with your dtor is that an exception will cause a memory leak (with some other problems relating to exceptions leaking out of dtor's).

Answer (score 0):

Don't deallocate anything in main().

The destructor for reportData will handle everything allocated with createfd() (just make sure that createfd() is returning what it allocated with new(), since you must not delete anything that was not new'd).

fileData is allocated locally, on the stack, not through new.  Since it wasn't allocated by new, don't delete it.

The pointers that were passed into fileData were also passed into reportData, and reportData is responsible for all deletions there.  You could check to see that they weren't allocated from an inaccessible memory pool (say in a dynamically linked library); if they were, that's a problem.

So, assuming the deletes are correct in the ReportData destructor, remove any deletion of fileData and you're good.